# Querying a site for a specific value

Tags: html, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to get a specific value into PowerShell from the site below.

http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/servicetag/9PXNF4J/configuration

The `Invoke-WebRequest` on PowerShell v3 works like a charm, but we dont have that luxury on all the servers.

I need the IDRAC ENTERPRISE value from the site

```
Class = "Troubleshooting-left-offset-20 col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7"
```

Would also like to use this same method for pulling values from other sites as well.

Comment: I am not getting any output from that script. That is for posting a search of some sort on google, where i am trying to pull info from a site.
Any further help with this scenario would be appreciated. I also do not see a field where i can add the class data that i am trying to get.

Comment: I am not getting the info i need with the other answer. Can i please get help with this exact request?